# How to remove page name url on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to remove page name url in Wordpress on first page

in picture red line.

[image]

Thanks you for you advice.

Comment: Mark it as the static front page (in Settings -> Read)

Comment: Go to Admin Panel -> left side -> Settings -> Set Permalink. Make it post name.

Comment: Thank you, but i set Permalink to /%postname%/.

Comment: I Need to hide url on index page 
https://pricedee.com/en/home-v2-en/ to https://pricedee.com/en/

Answer (score 1):

Please check below snapshot may be it will help you.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, But I want my url web pages without "home-v2-en" in the browser's address bar. 

For eample 
https://pricedee.com/en/home-v2-en/ 
shows like https://pricedee.com/en/ in the browser's address bar.

maybe like setting .htaccess only Front page https://pricedee.com/en/